# R maximum of series of vectors

Tags: r

I have 3 vectors.

```
v <- c(1,2,3)
v1<- c(4,8,6)
v3<- c(7,3,9)
```

I want a vector v5  with (7,8,9). Which function should i be using.
Please guide.

Comment: and have you tried using `max()` and `c()` together?

Comment: By the way: StackOverflow is not a "do-my-code-for-me" site. **You have to show some effort!** You have to try to help yourself before asking for help. Please [read this article](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: See, also, `pmax(v, v1, v3)`

Comment: @Barranka: I tried max. But it wasnt working,so posted the question.thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read about `pmax` it could be useful for you in this situation.

```
> pmax(v,v1, v3)
[1] 7 8 9
```

From the helpfile you can find that `pmax`

> Returns the parallel maxima of the input values.